# Perform the PHP operation in Python in Django

Tags: javascript, python, php, django, ajax

I am calling a php file from a javascript code in Django, it seems it is not able to find it. So i was thinking to call a python function that will perform the same operation as of the given in PHP.

the js code where im calling php file

```
var filename = new Date().toISOString();
//filename to send to server without extension 
//upload link 
var upload = document.createElement('a');
upload.href = "#";
upload.innerHTML = "Upload";
upload.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            console.log("Server returned: ", e.target.responseText);
        }
    };
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("audio_data", blob, filename);
    xhr.open("POST", "upload.php", true);
    xhr.send(fd);
})
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" ")) //add a space in between 
li.appendChild(upload) //add the upload link to li
```

Upload.php

```
print_r($_FILES);
//this will print out the received name, temp name, type, size, etc. 

$input = $_FILES['audio_data']['tmp_name']; //get the temporary name that PHP gave to the uploaded 
file 

$output = $_FILES['audio_data']['name'].".wav"; //letting the client control the filename is a rather 
bad idea 

//move the file from temp name to local folder using $output name 
move_uploaded_file($input, $output)
```

so basically this php file is setting the blob file in my server

Can anyone please help me to convert this php to python or even performing the same operation by ajax or some will too work

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: iklinac.. I am sending data from javascript to my python functions, did.nt got any docs related to that